# Does filename expansion failing to match any file cause a script to exit with 1?

Tags: bash

From Bash Manual, for filename expansion:

> If the `nullglob` option is set, and no matches are found, the word is removed.

My following script will return exit status 1.

- Can filename expansion failing to match any jpg file in my current directory cause my script to exit with 1?
- How can I rule out other possibility for exit status 1?

Thanks.

```
shopt -s nullglob

for i in *.{png,jpg};
do
    filename=${i##*/}
    basename=${filename%.*}
    [ ! -e ${basename}.pdf ] && convert  "$i"  ${basename}.pdf ;
done
```

Comment: Run the script with `bash -x` to see where it exits exactly, and why.

Comment: Does not exit with status 1 here, when running in a directory with no files matching the pattern.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks. without `shopt -s nullglob`, will no matching cause your script exit with 1?

Comment: @Tim Yes, since the commands in the loop fail.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks. I updated my script, because I missed the checking the pdf file existence in my oriignal post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, setting the `nullglob` shell option and failing to expand a glob pattern will not cause the script to exit with a non-zero exit status (and matching filenames with glob patterns in general does not change the `$?` shell variable).

*Not* setting `nullglob` will make `convert` fail (unless there are files with the literal names `*.jpg` and `*.png` in the current directory), and it will exit with an exit status of 1.

Since this is the last executed command in the script, the script will exit with this exit status.

---

After update to script in question:

The script now exits with a non-zero exit status *if* a PDF file exists for the last image file processed, due to the `[ ! -e ... ]` test (this is the last command executed in the script in that case).

If this is unwanted, use

```
[ ! -e "${basename}.pdf" ] && convert "$i" "${basename}.pdf" || true
```

(note also the added quoting)

Comment: Thanks. I updated my script, because I missed the checking the pdf file existence in my oriignal post. Can that be the reason for script exist status 1? How can I suppress that cause of exit status 1?

Comment: @Tim See update.